# Easiest way to search column value, match with a set value, and assign to a variable in python

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

Aim: check if my `bad_outcomes` set includes `df['Outcome']` pd dataframe column values. If the set does contain these values I want to assign them to a new variable `landing_outcome` with the value of 0. If not I assign `landing_outcome` a value of 1.

I am able to search a column `df['Outcome']` and check if the values are in my set called 'bad_outcomes' using isin.

```
df[df['Outcome'].isin (bad_outcomes)]
```

This works. Then I try to put this in an if statement

```
if df[df['Outcome'].isin (bad_outcomes)]:
    landing_outcome = 0
```

This gives me a Value error:

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Where I am going wrong?
Is using isin the best way to do this?

I checked python manual for if statements and could't find an obvious syntax issue, I searched this forum for the error message (there are many posts but I couldn't see one for my use case). I'm new, I hope this is ok to ask.

Comment: Your statement returns an array of Booleans, which in itself doesn't have a true/false value.  You should do exactly what the message suggests: `if df[df['Outcome'].isin (bad_outcomes)].any():`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.loc`

```
df.loc[df['Outcome'].isin(bad_outcomes), "landing_outcome"] = 0
df.loc[~df['Outcome'].isin(bad_outcomes), "landing_outcome"] = 1
```

If this helps, do approve the solution and upvote it.

Comment: Hey Raymond, thanks for taking the time. df.loc solution gives the set the value of 0 but I'm trying to give each item its own value of 0. If not in the set i assign 1.  Then i can add it as a new col in the df. I think my error was trying to us isin with an if statement. Posting my update below.

Comment: @James i have updated the answer. Do check it out!

Comment: thanks @Raymond, that's great. I can't upvote you because my reputation is 2 points short of the 15 i need to vote, but it works great and thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on condition statements on [codegrepper][1] which referenced this resource on stackoverflow

Which linked back to stackoverflow here: [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Using this approach my solution was:

```
landing_class=[0 if outcome in bad_outcomes else 1 for outcome in df['Outcome']]
```